# MyLocationOVerlay Vs LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, google-maps

What would be the difference between MyLocationOverLay and calling the function of LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates

In other words, if I am to show user location on the map while the user is moving, is the MyLocationEverlay enough or do I need to implement the requestLocationUpdates as well (or maybe not even use the former one?)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the MyLocationOverlay in my application to show the user's position and track his movement in the map screen. I have found it easy to use for that purpose similar to the way google maps works.

Here's a nice tutorial for you to use. [MyLocationOverlay Tutorial](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=148)